# python - pyqt5 QScrollBar of QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qscrollarea, qscrollbar

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled_1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 398, 298))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.listWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(4)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(5)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(6)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(7)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(8)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(9)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(10)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(11)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(12)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(13)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(14)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(15)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(16)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(17)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(18)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(19)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(20)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(21)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(22)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(23)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(24)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(25)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(26)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(27)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(28)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(29)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(30)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(31)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(32)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(33)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(34)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(35)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(36)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this example how can i hide the scrollbar of listwidget and instead have scrollbar of QMainWindow - QScrollArea?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the whole list being visible *within* the QScrollArea? May I ask you why you want to do this?

Comment: In this print screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4pyN.png i want the two lists to have height as big as it adjust the contents. If this height is bigger than a number the show the initial scrollbar of listwidgets

Comment: If the list contents are static, then just do `height = self.listWidget.frameWidth() * 2 + sum(self.listWidget.sizeHintForRow(i) for i in range(self.listWidget.count()))` then just `self.listWidget.setMinimumHeight(height)`. If it's dynamic, then you'll need to do something similar by overriding the `sizeHint()` in a subclass.